# Sentence structures with "felt "

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-usage

> - His words fell deep in my heart
> - I felt his words deep in my heart
> - His words made their way into my heart

Are they all grammatically correct? Do they mean the same?
Which one is more common?

Comment: There's nothing grammatically wrong with any of them; they just use different metaphors. Words can't literally 'fall' or 'make their way' into people's hearts. Which metaphor you use is your own stylistic choice.

Comment: Fell deep in my heart and fell deep into my heart.. are they both correct? I always tend to say deep into my heart. However, I see many use "in" instead of "into"

Comment: I agree that _fell into_ sounds better.

Comment: "His words fell deep in my heart" is grammatically correct, but sounds very strange and non-idiomatic.  [We don't usually say that words fall *in* or *into* anything](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=words+fell+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and saying that words [*fall on deaf ears*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall%20on%20deaf%20ears) is such a common idiom that saying "words fall" + anything else is likely to sound wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All of the sentences are grammatically valid. Their meanings are similar, but the use of different metaphors means there is at least a difference of nuance. Which to in any particular case use is a question of style.